# What is the definition of 'Wagenheims'?

Tags: meaning, loanwords

I'm reading an English translation of Notes from the Underground by Dostoevsky and I came across the sentence

> They express the consciousness that you have no enemy to punish, but
>   that you have pain; the consciousness that in spite of all possible
>   Wagenheims you are in complete slavery to your teeth...

I can't find any other uses of 'Wagenheims' online. It looks like it could be from German in which case it might mean something like 'ventures homewards', according to google translate, but it is not clear that this makes sense.

Comment: I doubt this has any relation to the English language. According to the commentary published in the Collected works of Dostoevsky -- [here in Russian](http://rvb.ru/dostoevski/02comm/24.htm#c5) -- it is a reference to the name of  the dentist(s) operating in St.Petersburg in 1860s.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Literature.SE; it is not a question about the workings of the English language but about a plot device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly [Martin K Wagenheim.](https://www.wilnitsky.com/scripts/redgallery1.dll/details?No=37138) a St. Petersburg dentist.

Answer (score -1):

Wagenheim is a proper name. No translation needed or possible.